# Not able to get dependency check report in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to get dependency check report for one of my Maven project but every time I am running:

```
mvn verify
```

dependency in dependency report shows no vulnerable JARs.

I have added below plugin in my POM to generate dependency check report:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2beta</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
          <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

What do I need to correct or is there any other way? `commons-email-1.1.jar` have some vulnerabilities but still its not getting detected.

These are the Maven logs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with 
nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ version-mana - 
 --
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ version- 
 mana ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ 
version-mana ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency-check-maven:3.3.2:check (default) @ version-mana ---
[INFO] Central analyzer disabled
[INFO] Checking for updates
[INFO] Skipping NVD check since last check was within 4 hours.
[INFO] Skipping RetireJS update since last update was within 24 hours.
[INFO] Check for updates complete (31 ms)
[INFO] Analysis Started
[INFO] Finished File Name Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished Dependency Merging Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished Version Filter Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished Hint Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Created CPE Index (1 seconds)
[INFO] Skipping CPE Analysis for npm
[INFO] Finished CPE Analyzer (1 seconds)
[INFO] Finished False Positive Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished NVD CVE Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished Vulnerability Suppression Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Finished Dependency Bundling Analyzer (0 seconds)
[INFO] Analysis Complete (1 seconds)
```

Comment: You might look through maven logs to check if the `check` goal has been executed at all.

Comment: @isnot2bad i have added maven logs . could you please check if its executing fine ?

Comment: Is there no "[_dependency-check-report.html in the target directory._"](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html) or is `commons-email-1.1.jar` not mentioned therein?

Comment: @GeroldBroser there is dependency check report in target folder . But its not listing out any vulnerable jars from pom (Yes - commons-email-1.1.jar not mentioned therein) .

Comment: Hm. Maven logs look fine at first sight.

Answer (score 8):

Provided you have access to the maven repository (at the time of executing this command) and installed mvn/mvnw , from the command-line, you can execute this line.

```
mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:5.2.2:check
```

The "dependency-check-report.html" report will be generated in the target folder.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest i tried it and for me it is working:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

dependency-check-maven tells me:

```
[INFO] Analysis Complete (1 seconds)
[WARNING] 

One or more dependencies were identified with known vulnerabilities in test:

commons-email-1.1.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.1, cpe:/a:apache:commons_email:1.1) : CVE-2017-9801, CVE-2018-1294


See the dependency-check report for more details.
```

How does your dependencies section look like? For Example if you define the scope test for commons-email no warning is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the response . When i am keeping all the dependencies inside <dependencyManagement> tag its not getting scanned but when i am removing dependencyManagement tag all the dependencies are getting scanned and even report is also getting generated with all the vulnerable jars . 
Not sure about this behavior of maven . Could you please let me know why dependencies are not getting scanned with dependencyManagement tag .

Comment: Have a look at [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). If you define a dependency only in dependencyManagement it will not be added to the classpath. So i believe thats how `dependency-check-maven` is working. It scans only the jars which are on the classpath. Maybe run maven with -X to see whats happening.